# Problem with mydaterangepicker and primeng, it is displaying bad into table header, can someone helpme please

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to use mydaterangepicker(https://kekeh.github.io/mydaterangepicker/) into primeng turbotable (primeng calendar does not comply with the requirements), but it doesn't display well. can you help with some css code or another solution please

I provide my source code, thank you:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fv53c6

Comment: have you try using css these `.selector {position: initial;}`

Comment: I tried, but it doesn´t work, thank you for help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the display of the calendar, instead of hiding inside the cell, putting it out in the open, put this in your app.component.css:

```
::ng-deep .mydrp { position:absolute !important;  }
::ng-deep .selectorarrow { position:absolute !important; }
::ng-deep .mydrp .selectiongroup {     margin-left: 12px;    top: -18px;     display: inline-table  !important;     border: 1px solid #CCC !important; }
::ng-deep .mydrp { border:none !important; }
::ng-deep body .ui-table .ui-table-thead > tr > th { height:45px !important; }
```

or check the [working demo which is forked against your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kraceq?file=src/app/app.component.css)

Comment: Thank you for help me, I almost get the solution, but it has a bad behavior when there is a scroll on the page, can you check the project again please?.... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fv53c6

Comment: When the date column is in the end of the table position absolute causes bad overflow of the date component
`this.cols = [
            { field: 'vin', header: 'Vin', width: 400 },
            { field: 'year', header: 'Year', width: 300 },
            { field: 'brand', header: 'Brand', width: 450 },
            { field: 'color', header: 'Color', width: 350 },
            { field: 'date', header: 'Date', width: 300}
        ];
`

Comment: can you share the updated stackblitz so that it is easier to see the effect and fix

Comment: I did it now. In the current example, you can see two scroll bars, in the table and page, and the date component shows with bad overflow. Thank you again

Comment: Good going... Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Your date picker is hidden because its parent's overflow is hidden.

You need to add `overflow:visible` to the parent of your `my-date-range-picker` and the div with `class="ui-table-scrollable-header ui-widget-header"`.